# How To Shift To Next Page while Printing Bar Codes Labels in c# I Have Outer loop That is Controling Which Item And Inner loop Having Required Copies

Tags: c#

I want to print 50 labels per sheet (5 columns and 10 rows). When it goes to the 11th row it should switch to the next page. I have tried `e.hasMorePages` in several ways, but sometimes it gets overlapped on the same page.

**Here is my code:**

```
private void MakingLabel(int curentIndex,List<BarcodesSpecs> List)   
{
   int ListRows = List.Count;
   BarcodesSpecs barcodesSpecs = List.ElementAt(curentIndex);
   BarCode_ItemCode = barcodesSpecs.ItemCodeMain;
   BarCode_Description = barcodesSpecs.Description;
   BarCode_SalePrice = barcodesSpecs.SalePrice;
   BarCode_Size = barcodesSpecs.Size;
   BarCode_Colour = barcodesSpecs.Colour;
   barCode_LabelToPrint = Convert.ToInt16(barcodesSpecs.QtyToPrint);
}

int xCord = 0, yCord = 0;
int CurentIndex = 0;
int MaxCharactersInString = 26;

private void printBarcodes_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   for (CurentIndex = 0; CurentIndex < BcList.Count; CurentIndex++)
   {
      MakingLabel(CurentIndex, BcList);

      for (int i = 0; i < barCode_LabelToPrint; i++) //// making Copies means How many Labels Of this Item Needed
      {
         if (xCord >= 750)
         {
            xCord = 0;
            yCord += 115;
         }
         if (BarCode_Description.Length > MaxCharactersInString)
         {
            BarCode_Description = BarCode_Description.Substring(0, MaxCharactersInString);
         }
         e.Graphics.DrawString("ALPIAL   SUITING", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(xCord, yCord + 10));
         e.Graphics.DrawString("Rs" + BarCode_SalePrice + "/-", new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(xCord, yCord + 21));
         e.Graphics.DrawString("Size: " + BarCode_Size + "  Colour: " + BarCode_Colour, new Font("Arial", 07, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(xCord, yCord + 42));
         e.Graphics.DrawString(BarCode_Description, new Font("Arial", 07, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(xCord, yCord + 52));
         e.Graphics.DrawString(BarCode_ItemCode, new Font("Arial", 06, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(xCord, yCord + 62));
         Zen.Barcode.Code128BarcodeDraw barcode = Zen.Barcode.BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum;
         e.Graphics.DrawImage(barcode.Draw(BarCode_ItemCode, 25), xCord, yCord + 72);

         xCord += 160;
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

The result I am getting is in the picture, any help will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Soory for the Picture it is in the link below
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AnFxwk_kR9bagdc7cGAsO8KUJmo4wA

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the line, you will need to check if yCord is beyond the bottom of the page. If it is, you need to set HasMorePages to true and exit the PrintPage handler. It will be called again for the next page. You'll have to keep track of which labels you have already printed outside the PrintPage handler and continue from that point.

Here's a sample I did to simulate labels printing.  I only drew a square to represent the label.  I had to do a little math to figure out the spacing so you will likely have to adjust this for your situation.

```
private static void doPrintPreview()
{
    var pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;

    var prv = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    prv.Document = pd;
    prv.ShowDialog();
}

//Units are in 1/100 of an inch
private static float leftMargin = 100f;        //Page margins
private static float rightMargin = 750f;
private static float topMargin = 100f;
private static float bottomMargin = 1000f;
private static int numLabelsToPrint = 200;     //How many we want to print
private static int numLabelsPrinted = 0;       //How many we have already printed
private static float labelSizeX = 75;         //Label size
private static float labelSizeY = 75f;
private static float labelGutterX = 7.14f;    //Space between labels
private static float labelGutterY = 7.5f;

static void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Display;    //Units are 1/100 of an inch

    //start at the left and top margin of the page for a new page
    float xPos = leftMargin;
    float yPos = topMargin;

    using (var p2 = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3.0f))
    {
        //While there are still labels to print
        while (numLabelsPrinted < numLabelsToPrint)
        {
            //Draw the label  (i just drew a square)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, xPos, yPos, labelSizeX, labelSizeY);
            numLabelsPrinted++;

            //Set the x position for the next label
            xPos += (labelSizeX + labelGutterX);

            //If the label will be printed beyond the right margin
            if ((xPos + labelSizeX) > rightMargin)
            {
                //Reset the x position back to the left margin
                xPos = leftMargin;
                //Set the y position for the next row of labels
                yPos += (labelSizeY + labelGutterY);

                //If the label will be printed beyond the bottom margin
                if ((yPos + labelSizeY) > bottomMargin)
                {
                    //Reset the y position back to the top margin
                    yPos = topMargin;

                    //If we still have labels to print
                    if (numLabelsPrinted < numLabelsToPrint)
                    {
                        //Tell the print engine we have more labels and then exit.
                        e.HasMorePages = true;

                        //Notice after setting HasMorePages to true, we need to exit from the method.
                        //The print engine will call the PrintPage method again so we can continue 
                        //printing on the next page.
                        break;   //you could also just use return here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So i Should Change the logic to While instead of for loop ? because when i put return It continues to print infinity pages
@Chris Dunaway

Comment: You don't strictly need a while loop.  I just chose it for this example.  You just need to keep track of how much you have printed _separately_ from the `PrintPage` method so that if you set `HasMorePages` to true, you will know where to continue printing.  Once you have printed all that you need to print, set `HasMorePages` to false and exit.  By the way, the reason my methods are static is because I was using a Console program for my example.